# How to manage Soft Deleted records in MYSQL 5.6?

Tags: mysql

I Needed some help on how to manage soft deleted records in MySQL.
We have a few million soft-deleted records.
As MYSQL does not have support for filtered indexes below are some solutions we are looking into

1. Add deleted columns to every index.
2. Remove all clustered indexes to enable MySQL query optimizer to use index merge
3. Use trigger to move deleted records in to achieve table

MYSQL version is 5.6. We are moving to 5.7 soon.

We have around 10 million records on the table. Around 4 Million are soft deleted. How do we ensure that query performance is optimal when we have 40% of records soft deleted?

When use deleted = 0 to mark the record as deleted.

Comment: Think about partitioning. Create `deleted` column in the table. Partition the table by this column value. Use explicit partition hint in your queries or implicit partition pruning.

Comment: I do not see any question in your post!

Comment: @Akina - I comment on Partitioning in my Answer.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @RickJames MYSQL version is 5.6, So we cannot use implicit partitioning as well.

Comment: @MacleanPinto - What new feature involves "implicit partitioning"?  (I don't know of a significant new feature after 5.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a "small" percentage of rows are soft-deleted, don't worry about performance.

If a "large" percentage of rows are soft-deleted, I would not trust "index merge" to be very useful.  And it could even be slower than what you have now.

What are the "important" queries?  That is which ones are important enough to optimize?  Do any important queries fetch both deleted and non-deleted rows?  (The changes being discussed may make them go slower.)

If you add `deleted` to an index *and* test for it, then be sure to test with `=` and put `deleted` first in the index.  That is, phrase the test as `delete = 0` or `deleted IS NULL` (eg, if `deleted` is a `DATE` that is `NULL` until it is deleted).  A test with anything other than `=` or `IS NULL` will not get past that column in the index.

It is almost always useless to have a "boolean" column in an `INDEX` by itself.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the size of the table, the percentage of "deleted", and the important queries.  Then I can provide more specific advice.

As for Partitioning on `deleted`, I cannot get excited.

- When "deleting" a record, the system has to effectively delete the row from one partition and insert it into the other.
- And my comments about the `WHERE` clause are still important.
- Adding partitioning would force the rebuilding of *all* the indexes.
- And you may need to redesign some of the indexes based on the partitioning.
- Every Unique (including Primary) index must include the partition key.  That may force at least one index change._

Are rows deleted one at a time?  If so, a 4th option is a stored proc that moves the row.

Or do you delete "old" rows?  If so, there is a good argument for Partitioning.  (It does not sound like this is your case.)

Comment: Do you delete "old" rows? Not as of now. We have to retain the records for an archival service which is a work in progress.